# Find Xpath on Website?

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs

I'm trying to do either an =ImportXML or =ImportHTML for
http://www.sportsline.com/nfl/odds/

I can't seem to get the importhtml to run, I've tried other index option as well.

```
=importhtml("http://www.sportsline.com/nfl/odds/","Table",0)
```

I'm not familiar with finding the Xcode, so i've been going in circles.

Hopefully someone could assist me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.sportsline.com/nfl/odds/", "//div[@class='row-group']")
```

Comment: Yes! That worked.  I was wondering how I could of found that out myself for future websites I may try to use.

Comment: Hey, this import no longer works, do you have any suggestions on what the new one might be.  I appreciated your help the last time. @Max